# How to replace All NULL Values in Data Frame made of lists?

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe

I have data frame (includes lists not factors) made from 100s of JSON files . I need to replace all NULL values with 0 . How can I achieve that ?

This is my script to read 100s JSON files into R dataframe , and most JSON files have 20 columns , and few have 18 columns [2 columns not there] , so where column value is missing in any JSON files , by default it creates NULL value for missing columns .

```
path<-"mypath"
files <- dir(path, pattern = "*.json")

mydf <- files %>%
map_df(~fromJSON(file.path(path, .), flatten = TRUE))
```

Just look at below example . First 2 JSON files have column_x values , but 3rd JSON file does not have any column with column_x name . So while reading files , my script creates NULL values in case of inconsistent column names across JSON files ... What I want is to change such NULL values as 0 in my data frame involving lists.

```
mydf[10]

   column_x
1  CSCvg17070
2  CSCvd08829
3  NULL
```

For producible purpose , my sample df is given below

```
mydf<-data.frame(col1=c(NULL,"b"),col2=c("f","j"))
mydf$col1<-as.list(mydf$col1)
mydf$col2<-as.list(mydf$col2)
str(mydf)
```

I tried to do the below , but it did not achieve desired results.

```
mydf[is.null(mydf)] <- 0
```

Comment: Yogesh, I don't think you are defining your example data.frame as you intend?  The NULL isn't populating, just two occurrences of "b" in col1?

Comment: @Yogesh Kumar, change `NULL` to `NA` so your example `data.frame` contains a missing value

Comment: @RussThomas : Yes , Null value is not populating I tried that , but in my original data frame I have NULL values , so I tried to create a data frame that is similar . my data frame involves lists as well , so found it difficult to get NULL as values .... I have updated my query with explanation

Comment: @ladylala : In my original data frame , I have NULL not NAs , pls refer to my updated comments in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I have found my solution as to how to replace all NULL values in data frame involving lists .

A is my data frame , and col1 is one of the columns (defined as list)

```
for(i in 1:length(A$col1))if(is.null(A$col1[[i]]))A$col1[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `NULL` to `NA` since `NULL` usually refers to something not existing, as opposed to a missing value (hope this is still accurate, even though it's from 2010: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/).

First, adjust your `data.frame` as @PoGibas suggested.

```
mydf<-data.frame(col1=c(NA,"b"),col2=c("f","j"))
mydf$col1<-as.list(mydf$col1)
mydf$col2<-as.list(mydf$col2)
str(mydf)
```

Now, your original command (except changing `is.null()` to `is.na()` should work:

```
mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- 0
##   col1 col2
## 1    0    1
## 2    1    2
```

Comment: Pls refer to my comments , when I read JSON files as data frame , by default I get NULL values for few columns in mydf , so I want to change those NULL values to 0... I cannot change NULL to NA as I have a data that has NULL values while loading JSON files into r

Comment: @YogeshKumar I'm sorry for the late response.  Would you mind updating your question with the output of `str(mydf)`?  I'm having difficulty generating your reproducible example, since it doesn't seem to line up with your description. Thanks!